# Find the selected column in the excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

```
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If Sheet.Index <> 1 Then
           Sheet.Activate
           Range("B1").Select
           Call Something
        ElseIf Sheet.Index = 1 Then
           Sheet.Activate
           Range("A1").Select
           Call Something_new
        End If
    Next Sheet
```

I'm doing a project, in which if I filter something in a (column)sheet it will synchronize in every other (column)sheet.
 In the above code, I'm using the **"if"** conditions based on the sheet index.
I need to use condition based on selected column, something like this

```
if filters are made on Column A Then 
Range("A1").select
Call something
if filters are made on Column B Then
Range("B1").select
Call something_else
```

I need some suggestions,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These basics might be exactly what you need - on a standard filtered sheet (sheet1 for me):

```
If Sheet1.AutoFilter.Filters.Item(1).On Then MsgBox ("Filter 1 is on")
```

Item 1 will be the first column, column A. You could test each one like so:

```
If Sheet1.AutoFilter.Filters.Item(1).On Then MsgBox ("Filter 1 is on")
If Sheet1.AutoFilter.Filters.Item(2).On Then MsgBox ("Filter 2 is on")
```

etc. or you could cycle through dynamically testing like this:

```
Sub SelectFirstColumnWithFilter
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Sheet1.AutoFilter.Filters.Count
        If Sheet1.AutoFilter.Filters.Item(i).On Then Cells(1, i).Select: Exit Sub
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: It would be good to previously check if there is a filter in place. Otherwise, the code stops on error. Something like 'If Not Sheet1.FilterMode Then 'worn in a way and Exit Sub`.

Comment: Yup you're right, code will error if there's no filter on the sheet, could include as a first line `If not Sheet1.FilterMode Then Exit Sub`